# ng2-bootstrap dynamic tabs are not removed when array element is deleted

Tags: angular, data-binding, ngfor, ng2-bootstrap

so its about the two-way binding between the tabs and the array, adding elements to the array works perfectly, but removing an element makes no effect

**Template:**

```
<tab *ngFor="let brand of brands; let i = index"
    [heading]="brand.title"
    [removable]="true"
    (removed)="removeBrand(i)">
</tab>
```

**Component:**

```
private brands = [
    { title: 'Ford' },
    { title: 'Renault' },
    { title: 'Hyundai' },
    { title: 'Porsche' },
]

private addAndDelete() {
    this.brands = this.brands.slice().splice(0, 1)
    this.brands.push({ title: 'newcar' })
}
```

when `addAndDelete()` is called, I only get an additional 'newcar' tab, but nothing removed. is that a bug or did I mess up somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you cannot have a `addAndDelete` method. Removing and adding should be in two separate methods!

So add:

```
add() {
  this.brands.push({title: 'newcar'})
}
```

in your tab you should have

```
(removed)="removeBrand(brand)"
```

and your remove-method:

```
removeBrand(brand) {
  let index = this.brands.indexOf(brand);
  this.brands.splice(index, 1);
}
```

this should work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work I had to do this:

```
@ViewChild(TabsetComponent) private tab: TabsetComponent;
removeBrand(brand){
  this.tab.removeTab(brand);
}
```